# What is wrong with this statement: $-\frac{1}{a} \gt \frac{1}{b}$ so $-b \gt a$

Tags: inequality

Suppose $$-\frac{1}{a} \gt \frac{1}{b}$$

=> $$-\frac{b}{a} > 1 $$

=> $$-b \gt a$$

Anything wrong with this argument?

Comment: Suppose $a = -1, b = 2$. You have to flip direction of the inequality if multiplying by a negative number. Be careful.

Comment: Multiplying/dividing by negative numbers reverses the direction of an inequality. We do not know from the outset what sign $a$ or $b$ are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are doing is:
-1/a * b > (1/b) * b
The issue here is the b could be negative. If b is indeed negative, then the inequality sign would change. NOW, since you also multiply both sides by a, a could be negative as well and would require an inequality sign change (greater than vs less than). If a is neg and b is pos, then your final inequality is wrong. If b is neg and a is pos, then your final inequality is still wrong. IF both integers are negative, then your final argument is accurate.